# What is the meaning of class attribute in view

Tags: android, android-layout

I found following class attribute in xml file fo view

class="com.example.android.apis.view.VideoPlayerActivity$Content"

on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html
what is the meaning of using fully qualified class names in xml files in android.
How this class is used while inflation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes you will find default components to be insufficient for your needs. You can use this `class` attribute in order to use your own components inside xml file.

For example let's assume that you have created your own component which extends `TextView` with some additional functionality and you named it `MyTextView`. You can use it in xml file like this:

```
<view
  class="com.project.my.MyTextView" 
  id="@+id/note"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

You might want to read further in Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Answer (score 4):

```
<view
  class="A_public_view_Inner_class_full_package" 
  id="@+id/note" />
```

Equivalent to

```
<A_public_view_class_full_package
  id="@+id/note"
  ...>

<A_public_view_class_full_package/>
```

**BUT < view class="A_public_view_Inner_class_full_package" is Used If the class is Inner class** in Java programming.

Back to your case. Because VideoPlayerActivity$Content is Inner class so you must use < view class="" syntax.

**You cannot use this definition for Inner class**

```
<com.example.android.apis.view.VideoPlayerActivity$Content
  id="@+id/note"
  .... />
```

**UPDATE:Someone may ask this question: Why Android does not use** < com.example.android.apis.view.VideoPlayerActivity$Content .../>**instead of using** < view class="" />. **The simple answer is XML element name can't contain '$' that appear in Inner class name.**

**Conclusion:**

- If the view class is not Inner class, use normal way to define View in XML.
- If the view is Inner class --> Use < view class = "" to define View in XML.

Comment: I was just wondering why different syntax for inner class.We can distinguish using $ sign.why can't we use the definition without  class tag for inner class as well ?